# Not able to print the exact EMA 200 value

Tags: pine-script

Below is the snippet of code I am trying to run to print the 5m EMA200 value of
Nifty! (Nifty Continuous Current Month Contract)

```
get_EMA200_Stats_res(_res)=> request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _res,ta.ema(close,200) , lookahead =barmerge.lookahead_on)
ema200_5m = get_EMA200_Stats_res("5")
```

What I get is 20017447.46525553431.
The actual value of 5m EMA200 is 17447.

Could someone please clarify as to why these additional numbers are getting pre/postfixed?
How do I avoid them and get only the EMA value..in this case 17447.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

which uses an offset of `[1]` on the series
[nonRepaintingSecurityAlternate()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#repainting-request-security-calls)

something like that:

```
get_EMA200_Stats_res(_res)=> request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _res,ta.ema(close,200)[1] , lookahead =barmerge.lookahead_on)
ema200_5m = get_EMA200_Stats_res("5")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Giving offset doesn't seem to be helping me out. I tried couple of approaches as mentioned in the reference URL you had given. None of them worked. If you want me to trying anything else please do let me know. Thanks much!